Are there any sources of the approximate width of azhdarchid wing limbs?
Are there any sources with approximate calculations on how wide the front limbs of azhdarchid pterosaurs, especially hatzegopteryx should/would be? I've been searching but most of what I've found were papers describing the length of certain bones, the closest I've found being certain descriptions of the humerus.

wingspan is approximately 12 meters, from the orginal descrption.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/11313784_A_new_giant_pterosaur_with_a_robust_skull_from_the_Latest_Cretaceous_of_Romania
Your not getting anything more detailed than that becaue we don't have a complete wing, only a reconstructionf from parts of the wing bones. This is really common with very large animals, its just hard to get all of a large animal in the right conditions for preservation.
https://markwitton-com.blogspot.com/2017/01/new-paper-when-short-necked-giant.html
for anything more detailed your best bet is to take measurments from reconstruction images. they are created using the best anitomical knowledge available so they are the best you will get.
